# Group by two dimensions and count in Elixir

Tags: elixir, reduce

I'm looking at grouping with two dimensions, then counting the number of each elements in each category / subcategory.

```elixir
data = [
  %{brand: "Mercedes", color: "blue"},
  %{brand: "Mercedes", color: "blue"},
  %{brand: "BMW", color: "blue"},
  %{brand: "BMW", color: "blue"},
  %{brand: "BMW", color: "blue"},
  %{brand: "Lada", color: "blue"},
  %{brand: "Mercedes", color: "red"},
  %{brand: "Mercedes", color: "red"},
  %{brand: "Mercedes", color: "red"},
  %{brand: "Mercedes", color: "red"},
  %{brand: "BMW", color: "black"}
]
```

expected result:

```elixir
[
  %{"Mercedes": ["blue": 2, "red": 4]},
  %{"Lada": ["blue": 1]},
  %{"BMW": ["blue": 3, "black": 1]}
]
```

I have something that is close from the result, but it's not exactly what I want:

```elixir
per_brands = Enum.group_by(data, fn (item) -> [item[:brand]] end)
Enum.map(
  per_brands,
  fn (cars_per_brand) ->
    %{
      "#{elem(cars_per_brand, 0)}": (
        Enum.map(
          Enum.group_by(elem(cars_per_brand, 1), fn (car) -> car[:color] end),
          fn (cars_per_brands_per_colors) ->
            %{"#{elem(cars_per_brands_per_colors, 0)}": Enum.count(elem(cars_per_brands_per_colors, 1))}
          end
        ))
    }
  end
)

# Result: (not exactly what I want)
[
  %{BMW: [%{black: 1}, %{blue: 3}]},
  %{Lada: [%{blue: 1}]},
  %{Mercedes: [%{blue: 2}, %{red: 4}]}
]
```

I believe there is something smarter and better to do with `reduce/3`, but I can't wrap my head around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with reduce like this:

```elixir
Enum.reduce(data, %{}, fn %{brand: brand, color: color}, acc ->
  colors = Map.get(acc, brand, %{}) |> Map.update(color, 1, &(&1 + 1))
  Map.put(acc, brand, colors)
end)
```

For each brand/color pair, build up a map of maps, incrementing the color counts as they are found.

Result:

```elixir
%{
  'BMW' => %{'black' => 1, 'blue' => 3},
  'Lada' => %{'blue' => 1},
  'Mercedes' => %{'blue' => 2, 'red' => 4}
}
```

Comment: This is neat, thanks. I ended up with another way to go with Reduce, which uses the `Access.key` method. That one was quite hard to understand, but in the end it works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed doing something better than my initial approach with a `Map.Reduce` and `Access.key/2` as well:

```elixir
Enum.reduce(
  data,
  %{},
  fn (item, acc) ->
    new_value = if (acc[item[:brand]][item[:color]]) do
      # The value already exists
      acc[item[:brand]][item[:color]] + 1
    else
      # The value does not exist, initialize to 1
      1
    end

    acc = put_in(acc, [Access.key(item[:brand], %{}), item[:color]], new_value)
  end
)
```

I think the @adam solution is neater though.